# SoapUI testrunner.bat unable to delete temporary directories after test run

Tags: soapui, testcase, test-suite

While running a test on SoapUI via testrunner.bat, it cannot delete the temporary directories that are created for the needs of the test. So, despite of having the status "FINISHED", it shows me the following message:

- Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\F8C6B~1.PAP\AppData\Local\Temp\79461277-c0d0-45fc-8a58-7c66bcc08ca9
- Could not delete temporary directory C:\Users\F8C6B~1.PAP\AppData\Local\Temp\ec6bd83a-e577-4b14-a523-fc2c083945ac.

Does anyone know why it can't delete those directories?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wdqf.jpg

I have tried to execute it as an admin, but there was no difference.

Comment: Do you still find them after reboot of the machine?